# Transferring files from one App to the any other app in the same Device

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, converters, file-transfer

I have an app which converts files like from .png to .pdf etc. Now I want to open these converted files in any other app which supports viewing of such files like a pdf Viewer etc. I have made a sample App which identifies the various other applications in the same device and I can open my files in them also ***But*** all these apps **are launched in the Apple store.**

The **Main Issue** is that how do i test this functionality in my app which is in testing phase and is not put up on the Apple store ?

I used the following code for opening the other apps :-

```
- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL:(NSURL *)fileURL
                                               usingDelegate:(id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>)         interactionDelegate {

    UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController =
    [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
    interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;

    return interactionController;
}

- (void)showOptionsMenu
{
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ifiles-converter-lite-convert/id576154331?ls=1&mt=8"];
    docController = [self setupControllerWithURL:fileURL
                                   usingDelegate:self];
    bool didShow = [docController presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:_btnActions
                                                             animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Not a solution but a comment. What I have discovered in my own experiments when trying to share a PDF from one app to another is when you send a file across two app, what you're actually doing is creating a separate "clone" of the file at that point in time, you are not passing the original file across.

In other words, if you modify the PDF in the second application for example, the original PDF will NOT be modified. All you're modifying is the clone. You can test your app by trying to send your PDF to iBooks  from your own app.

Comment: @Zhang the issue is not of modification but to identify that app which has been loaded for testing and not downloaded from the Apple store....

Comment: So you want to prevent non-apple store apps from viewing your PDF? Wasn't clear what your question was from the title and description.

Comment: @Zhang sorry for the confusion but i simply want to open my converted files or zipped files in another app and vice-cersa ...